# How to share external libraries between multiple angular elements

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid-angular, angular-elements, ngx-build-plus

I'm currently working with Angular Elements and more specifically trying to make multiple Elements communicate and interact with each other. In my case, the two elements I am trying to create share an external library (ag-grid) which enables them to display an advanced table which the user can interact with.

My question was regarding the bundling of these two elements. Currently, I am building the two elements separately using ngx-build-plus. The output gives me 2 main.js, 2 scripts.js, 2 polyfills.js, ... files and my goal would be to have 1 main.js file per element, and only 1 scripts.js file that would be shared between all of the elements.

ngx-build-plus allows us to create a webpack.external.js that lists the dependecies that would be shared:

```
module.exports = {
    "externals": {
        "rxjs": "rxjs",
        "@angular/core": "ng.core",
        "@angular/common": "ng.common",
        "@angular/common/http": "ng.common.http",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "ng.platformBrowser",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "ng.platformBrowserDynamic",
        "@angular/compiler": "ng.compiler",
        "@angular/elements": "ng.elements",

        // Uncomment and add to scripts in angular.json if needed
        // "@angular/router": "ng.router",
        // "@angular/forms": "ng.forms"
    }
}
```

I've been trying to add ag-grid-angular to this file and also to the "scripts" array in the angular.json but I haven't had any success as I do not have much experience with Angular or Angular Elements.

Comment: any solution that you found?

Comment: repo for Angular 13 with example for webpack externals https://github.com/peterblazejewicz/angular-umd-bundle